# Dynamic image selection with multiple languages in PHP/Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm adding multiple language support to my Codeingiter/PHP app and I'm trying to determine a good approach for handling the images.

For text I'm using the i18n and Codeingiter's native Language class.

Proposed code for dynamic image selection:

```
if ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'br') { Brazilian image link } else { English image link }
```

For images within CSS files, I'm planning on processing them as PHP files and then using the same code as above.

Are there any potential flaws with this approach? It seem cumbersome, wondering if these is a more efficient approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any way around using PHP or some other scripting language to have variable CSS. This page might give you some ideas.

[How to Add Variables to Your CSS Files](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-add-variables-to-your-css-files/)

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty much what I was thinking. Thanks for confirming, the links looks quite good.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend storing the language in the session and modifying it according to the segment of the URI. Performing this in the constructor will save you a lot `if` and `else` in your code.

In order to dynamically load an image use a naming convention of this sort: `imagename_lang.ext`, IE: `homepage_br.jpg`.

The loading will look like this: `echo "homepage_$this->session->userdata('lang').jpg"` or if you store it first in a variable like this:
`echo "homepage_$lang.jpg"`

For images in the CSS, split the CSS file into three:

1. style.css - Stores all the styling which is not language sensitive.
2. style_en.css - Stores all the images for the English version.
3. style_br.css - Storess all the images for the Brazilian version.

This way you will only need to make a single check of the language, when you are including the appropriate CSS file.